# Парсинг Ethernet фреймов с помощью FPGA( + Raspberry/Arduino)

Tags: железо, arduino, raspberry-pi, ethernet

Добрый день!

Возник следующий вопрос. Имеюются отладочная плата на Altera Cyclone IV, Arduino Mega и Raspberry Pi.

Задача заключается в том, чтобы создать прозрачное(без собственного IP-адреса) устройство, которое бы выполняло такие функции: получало ethernet frame, деинкапсулировало и изменяло его содержимое, запаковывало бы назад в ethernet frame и отправляло дальше получателю.

Пока мыслю так: можно ли каким-то образом поднять прием/передачу данных на Raspberry, затем отпралять их на FPGA, там обрабатывать(предположим шифровать), затем возвращать на Raspberry и отправлять дальше по сети.

Скорость передачи данных не так важна, достаточно было бы реализовать для 10/100 Fast Ethernet.

Физически это выглядит, как "разрез" провода UTP, в который и подключается мой девайс.

Скорее всего, можно создать такое устройство не используя Raspberry или Arduino, но мне хотелось бы уменьшить количество дополнительной схемотехнику, и я думаю, что малинка или ардуино могут в этом помочь.

Благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: А зачем FPGA если есть raspbery, мощности камня не хватает на выполнение всех операций (с учетом возможностей графического ядра для выполнения расчетных задач, той же криптографии)?

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за комментарий. FPGA хочу применять по таким причинам: 1) Все же скорость шифрования на нем довольно заметно выше 2) Хочу поупражняться с FPGA.

Comment: ммм. вообще-то прозрачный бридж на линуксах поднимается без проблем. Что-то такого плана http://flylib.com/books/en/3.105.1.89/1/
а далее в файрволле можно творить с пакетами любой беспредел...